# JavaFX ScrollPane scroll bars not showing if contained Group of nodes is zoomed in

Tags: javafx

I have a group of nodes. The first node added is an `ImageView`.
Then this group is set as content child node for a scrollable pane.
The group is bound to a scale transformation in order to resize the group.

If added an event filter to the scrollable pane in order to recognise if CTRL and the mouse wheel is used. This should create the zoom in and zoom out operations I need.

The problem is that the scrollable pane is not changing the bars according to the zoomed in or zoomed out group.

Here is the code snippet

```
Group group = new Group();

ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
sp.setVbarPolicy(ScrollBarPolicy.ALWAYS);
sp.setContent(group);

InputStream is = MaApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("test.jpg");
Image img = new Image(is);
ImageView viewer = new ImageView(img);
viewer.setFitWidth(600);
viewer.setPreserveRatio(true);
viewer.setDisable(true);
viewer.setCache(true);

group.getChildren().add(viewer);

DoubleProperty zoomProperty = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1);      

Scale scaleTransformation = new Scale();
scaleTransformation.xProperty().bind(zoomProperty);
scaleTransformation.yProperty().bind(zoomProperty);

group.getTransforms().add(scaleTransformation);

sp.addEventFilter(ScrollEvent.SCROLL, new EventHandler<ScrollEvent>() {
   @Override
   public void handle(ScrollEvent event) {
      if (event.isControlDown() && event.getDeltaY() > 0) {
        zoomProperty.set(zoomProperty.get() * 1.1);         
      } else if (event.isControlDown() &&  event.getDeltaY() < 0) {
        zoomProperty.set(zoomProperty.get() / 1.1);
      }
   }
});
```

I don't want to use a `StackPane` instance as it is used in different examples. The should be a solution for this using `Group` instead.
If you find this question to be a duplicate, please add a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ScrollPane` uses [the `layoutBounds` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#layoutBoundsProperty--) to determine the size, not [`boundsInParent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#boundsInParentProperty). `layoutBounds` does not include transformations. `layoutBounds` is just the size as determined by the `Node`'s geometry before the transformations are applied. Therefore the `ScrollPane` still considers the size to be the size of the **untransformed** `content`.

To fix this you could either apply the transformation to the child of the `Group` (`Group` takes transformations of children into account when determining it's own size)

```
// group.getTransforms().add(scaleTransformation);
viewer.getTransforms().add(scaleTransformation);
```

or wrap the `content` in another `Group`

```
sp.setContent(new Group(group));
```

If you want to add multiple nodes to the `Group`, you should use the second approach.

Comment: Second approach was a good idea. Can you further explain what you mean with "Transformations of the node itself are not applied to determine the size of the content Node". Is the change of the size not propagated?

Comment: @Mr.Mountain It's not propagated in a way that `ScrollPane` considers relevant for determining the size of the content. I've reformulated description a bit.